# std::vector of <key-value> pairs with different types

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair

I am trying to create a small interface function and to send it to a JSON formatter class.
The JSON works only with (unlimited) key-value pairs, but the value can be (only): `string, int, bool`

Now I have:

```
struct Data
{   
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int64_t>> intData;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> strData;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, bool>> boolData;
};

void func(const Data& data);
```

But I don't really like it (3 almost similar structures in `Data`), perhaps there is a better C++ way.

Ideally for me is to have something (templated) cleaner and to work like:

```
// pseudocode, I know that it does not work

struct Data
{   // AnyType = string, int or bool
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, AnyType>> data;
};

// or better
using Data = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, AnyType>> data;

Data data;
data.add("int value", 1);
data.add("string value", "str");
data.add("bool value", false);

func(data);
```

Thanks

LE: I am using C++11, cannot use another standard unfortunately.

Comment: What about `std::variant<std::int64_t, std::string, bool>`?

Comment: You may also consider using `std::any`.

Comment: Thank you all for the ideas, especially @Evg. Unfortunately I am stuck with C++11, I will edit my post, so `std::variant` is not an option :(

Answer (score 3):

One solution that springs to mind would be to use a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to get *compile time* *polymorphism*, ie.:

```
std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::variant<int64_t, std::string, bool>>>;
```

With *type alias*:

```
using json_val = std::variant<int64_t, std::string, bool>;
std::vector< std::pair<std::string, json_val>>;
```

---

*A note about json and overall approach:*

If you don't need to discriminate on the type intermediately or perhaps can't use a variant, it might be even simpler to just use a `std::string` for all value types. Since it is *json* this could make sense, since *json* data format doesn't have types like `int64_t`, ie. *json* just have numbers which are represented with strings.
(this is then recognized with a parsing which is what I think you are trying to model into an intermediate format).

Comment: `std::variant` can be very tricky to use right if you've never seen it before. I think an example of using `std::visit`or `get_if` would help complete this answer.

Comment: @darune great idea, unfortunately I am stuck with C++11, `std::variant` is in 17. I will edit my first post to be more clear.

Comment: @Taw Boost has an implementation of `variant` that, I believe, works in C++11.

Comment: I know, we don't use boost either in our company, we try to limit the 3rdparty as much as we can because of past problems (only openssl, curl and nlohmann json)

Comment: @Taw, then you can emulate `std::variant` with a `union` and an index (internally, `std::variant` is a union with an index).

Comment: @Taw The question is which is better — to use an additional third-party library with a well-proven solution, or write your own. Variants are not so easy to implement well, so the second option may be, in the end, much more problematic.

Comment: I understand but I work in the OEM business and our customers(big names) do not like at all to use 3rdparties. (because they need to add licenses for them, also). Thanks again for all your suggestions.